# regex search fail with special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to make a regex search in JavaScript, but it doesn't work with special characters such as `$` and `+`.

```
var string = "Keto After 50 $20 CPA+FS";
string.search(/Keto After 50 $20 CPA F+S/g);
```

I expect a match and a result of 0 instead of -1.

Comment: Special characters should be preceded by a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

We might just want to escape metachars:

```
(Keto After 50 \$20 CPA\+FS)
```

#### Test

```js
const regex = /(Keto After 50 \$20 CPA\+FS)/gm;
const str = `Keto After 50 \$20 CPA+FS`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### [Please see this demo for additional info.](https://regex101.com/r/PIxcyF/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can escape these special characters using a backslash (`\`):

```js
var string = "Keto After 50 $20 CPA+FS";
console.log(string.search(/Keto After 50 \$20 CPA\+FS/g));
```

Also, you had a typo in your regex. I guess you meant to match "...CPA+FS", not "...CPA F+S".

Answer (score 0):

Special characters should be preceded by a backslash.
In a JavaScript regex, the following characters are special:

```
[ \ ^ $ . | ? * + ( )
```

So your code should be as follows:

```
var string = "Keto After 50 $20 CPA+FS";
string.search(/Keto After 50 \$20 CPA\+FS/g);
```